# Ovirt VM starts without ipaddr and dns

Tags: ovirt

I am running self-hosted-ovirt engine (4.2) on centos (7.4).

I am trying to deploy vanilla test vm with ipaddr and dns to check the ssh connectivity. However the ansible playbook (below snippet) runs without error but when i try to see vm status, i do not see the ipaddr hence cannot ping or ssh to new vm.

```
- name: Add vanilla vm
  ovirt_vms:
     auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
     name: test01
     cluster: Default
     state: running
     memory: 2GiB
     cpu_cores: 8
     operating_system: rhel_7x64
     high_availability: true
     high_availability_priority: 50 # Available from Ansible 2.5
     cloud_init:
        nic_boot_protocol: static
        nic_ip_address: 10.34.60.86
        nic_netmask: 255.255.252.0
        nic_gateway: 10.34.63.254
        nic_name: eth1
        nic_on_boot: true
        host_name: test01.ovirt.dw
        custom_script: |
            write_files:
            - content: |
               Hello, world!
               path: /tmp/greeting.txt
               permissions: '0644'
               user_name: root
               root_password: super_password
      nics:
         - name: vnet0
      network: ovirtmgmt
      profile: ovirtmgmt
      interface: virtio
```

Is something missing or needs to be passed on on top of these?

Answer (score 0):

As per your script you are not using any template, so it's by default created from `Blank` template which don't have any OS installed. You must first create some template with OS installed and create virtual machine from that template.

Also please note that IP address of the virtual machine is reported only when guest agent is installed on the virtual machine, so it's better to have it pre-installed in the template. Here you have how-to install the guest agent:

https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/how-to/guest-agent/install-the-guest-agent-in-centos/